# How to make a data field optional (not required) in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, rest, java-8, jersey, jax-rs

I have a RESTapi written using Jersey Framework. Along with it there is a POJO class. Now, my need is how do I make a particular field optional in my POJO so that the api will work regardless of that optional field? I want the API should work in both the cases, i.e

1. if I give that optional parameter then also,
2. if I don't give then also it should work.

Comment: show us your code

Comment: just use - if(var == null){//some code} else{optional code}

Comment: **Optional does not implement Serializable, which is generally necessary for widespread use as a property of an object.** Becareful in what you wanna do.

Answer (score 2):

**Java 8's** Optional was mainly intended for return values from methods, and not for data properties of Java classes(POJO), as described in Optional in [Java SE 8](http://blog.joda.org/2014/11/optional-in-java-se-8.html):

> Of course, people will do what they want. But we did have a clear
>   intention when adding this feature, and it was not to be a general
>   purpose Maybe or Some type, as much as many people would have liked us
>   to do so. **Our intention was to provide a limited mechanism for library
>   method return types** where there needed to be a clear way to represent
>   "no result", and using null for such was overwhelmingly likely to
>   cause errors.
>
> The key here is the focus on use as a return type. **The class is
>   definitively not intended for use as a property of a Java Bean.**
>   Witness to this is that Optional does not implement Serializable,
>   which is generally necessary for widespread use as a property of an
>   object.

[credits] : https://blog.joda.org/2014/11/optional-in-java-se-8.html

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking about `java.util.Optional`, but about making something optional (as in, not required).

Comment: I inferred that he is talking about `java.util.Optional` , OP should clarify it in question. thanks @MarkRotteveel for the nudge :)

Comment: I actually found this answer useful when I _was_ looking for an answer for `java.util.Optional` so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are referring to the serialisation of fields in your POJO. Since you have not stated which version of jackson you are using, you'll have to use one of these annotations to allow nulls:

Can be used on either class or getter:

`@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)`

If you are using Jackson <2.x, use this:

`@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)`

Comment: You are going to JSON data not to class fields.